# How to Dynamically Update AJAX GET request headers with new token

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to set up an AJAX get request, which uses a variable as its headers, however, I'm struggling to find out how to use a variable for headers. Below is the get request. I've gotten to the point where I've captured the token in a variable in the format seen under var token. but how to use this variable as the headers?

```
    $('#get-product').click(function() {
  var token = 'Authorization' : 'token 123456789'
   $.ajax({
    url: 'someurl',
    data: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
     headers: {
                token,
            },
    processData: true,
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
        $('#response').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Headers constructor and use append to add the header option, your code will look like this:

```js
$('#get-product').click(function() {
  const headers = new Headers();

  headers.append('Authorization', 'token 123456789');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'someurl',
    data: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    headers,
    processData: true,
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
        $('#response').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like my main issue is that I wasn't passing the variable as json. So I instead reformatted the variable using JSON.stringify & .replace() so it was compatible.